# Configuring xorg.conf to split physical monitor into multiple "virtual" monitors

Tags: linux, xorg, xorg.conf

I am running the Qubes 3.2 (https://qubes-os.org) operating system with the awesome window manager installed and recently purchased an ultrawide 49" screen. I wish to partition my one physical monitor into 2 smaller monitors on the edges and one larger in the center to accommodate my particular needs.

AwesomeWM apparently have support for creating these fake screens (https://awesomewm.org/doc/api/classes/screen.html#screen:fake_add), but only from version 4. Qubes only supports awesome 3.5.9, which means I cannot use this API.

My next option was to try fakeXrandR (https://github.com/phillipberndt/fakexrandr) which may alleviate my problems, but upon reading the description over there it seems that I should be able to do this without fakexrandr

> Also note: With xrandr 1.5, this library shouldn't be needed anymore
> for most users. xrandr has an abstraction for "monitors" now which
> should work out of the box, at least with applications written using
> one of the big GUI frameworks.

Running xrandr -v in a terminal reveals

> xrandr program version       1.4.3
>
> Server reports RandR version 1.5

so I assume I should be able to do it, given the information from the description is correct.

I am not sure how to proceed to configure my xorg.conf to make this happen though. I have searched a lot, but couldn't find any information on this, which is why I am asking here.

Comment: Found [this](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/xorg/2017-March/058634.html), apparently it's not obvious. In what way do you want to access your virtual smaller monitors? As separate screens :0.0, :0.1 and :0.2? Or scrollable views into a single big framebuffer on a single screen :0.0?

Comment: Nice find! Yeah, ideally I would like to access them as separate screens, as I would like to have three different workspaces in the awesome window manager. Seems like some of the commands they mention, like 'xrandr --listmonitors' does not work for me.

Comment: I meant screens as in "X screens", not as in "WM workspaces". These are very different concepts, for example you'd need a different DISPLAY, and you won't be able to move an application to a different X screen.

Comment: If you mean "WM workspaces", `xrandr` or `xorg.conf` is the wrong way in the first place: WM workspaces just manipulate the window position/visibility, so if you want "multiple WM workspaces on one display", the only way is to use a WM that offers these.

Comment: @dirkt But awesome will handle different physical monitors by associating a new workspace with each screen. It is possible to handle in version of awesome greater than 4, but unfortunately I am stuck with 3.5.9.

Comment: I'll take this as a "yes, I want different VM workspaces on a single screen". I assume that means different physical monitors with Xinerama enabled? I still don't see a way to do that with xrandr (though that doesn't mean it's not possible in some way I don't see). In your place, the first thing I'd have done is to get the source code for awesome version 4, and compile it myself. (But I'm used to compiling stuff myself).

Comment: Yeah, I am going to try compiling awesome 4.2, however the OS I use (Qubes) does not seem compatible with that since it needs a bunch of patches for the particular version it uses now. I will take on the challenge though and try to make it happen, but still wanted to see if I could set up my workstation to maximize my productivity.